# Can you keep search params in the url after going to another page?

Tags: react-router

New programmer here who is messing around with lots of stuff.
So, i have this article searching application.
There is an input, you write stuff and it shows you articles containing the term that you used. Then you can go back and forth between pages of articles.

/home/?term=&page=0

When i click one of the articles, it takes me to a summary page with, well, a summary of the said article.

/home/article

What i want to do is, being able to go back to the home page with the last search parameters still intact.
Think of it similar to how google doesn't take you to just plain google.com but instead to the last search page that you were in.

How can i do that?

Small edit: if there is a way to just go back to the last page(With search params intact) without needing to put it in the URL or something similar, that is similarly fine of course.

Comment: You can issue a back navigation. You can also issue a regular navigation and append any current queryString. What have you tried? Please include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you are trying to use so we may see what any potential issue is and make the best suggestions possible, otherwise we can only speculate what your code is doing and spitball any solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React Router v6 you can use `navigate(-1)` as documented here: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate

Example:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const MyComponent = () => {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    
    const goBack = () => {
        navigate(-1);
    }
    
    return <button onClick={() => goBack()}>Back</button>
}
```

Comment: Oh jeez, thank you so much honestly. I thought that it would just reset the params...